# Windows 10 desktop icon grid broken on cold-start

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons, desktop

A few days ago I had some problems with my Windows pc. When I started the PC the explorer.exe wouldn't start correctly and I had to force-shutdown my PC.

After that, every time I start my PC in the morning, my desktop icon grid is broken. All icons are ordered in a grid filling the whole screen. The icons have a large horizontal spacing. Since the are to many icons for this kind of grid, some icons overlap in the top left corner.

If I restart the PC through the restart-button the problem fixes itself, however this is not a solution for me, as I do not want to restart the pc every time I start it.

[view of the broken window icon grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8J9h6.jpg)

If already looked at the registry entries under Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics but they have the same values before and after the restart.

The entry IconSpacing has a value of -1710 and IconVerticalSpacing has a value of -1125.

[Registry values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSgqL.jpg)

I want to avoid a complete Windows 10 reinstall if it's possible.

Edit: I haven't gotten around to trying the proposed solutions. My Windows decided to start working properly again today. Unfortunately, I can't say why it's working now. But I hope the answers can help other people.

Comment: I take it you have tried the usual *dism* and *sfc* commands to try to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> I had some problems with my Windows pc. When I started the PC the
> explorer.exe wouldn't start correctly and I had to force-shutdown my
> PC.

There appears to be enough problems that you should do a Windows 10 Repair Install.

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.
>
> Begin with the first option to Keep Everything and see if that works.
>
> There are more aggressive options if you need them:  Keep only Data,
> Keep Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You may check if you have restore-points: 1st. "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Recovery". 2nd. "Open System Restore". You may have a restore-point that will eliminate the problem you describe, without "a complete Windows 10 reinstall".